# JavaScript obfuscators with an output map

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I have an Javascript API which I would like to use online and obfuscate for unauthorised users. My class names are used in strings in the code (i.e. it's dymanic) and I also have some class names which are in XML files and all of these need to be obfuscated too in order for the whole to be usable. My idea was to use a Javascript obfuscator which is able to provide me with a map of the original and new (meaningless) name for each obfuscated symbol. Then I would be able to post-process the js and XML to apply the same mappings there. I've looked at Google's Closure Compiler and UglifyJS, but neither seem to provide this map. I am now looking at Jscrambler and other non-free obfuscators.
Can anybody recommend a tool which is able to properly obfuscate code and give me the required to do this post-processing?
Thanks
R

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it using the symbol table provided by the [jscambler API](https://jscrambler.com/en/webapi/v2/rest#symbol_table):

> "the symbol table contains key-value pairs representing the source code
>   names and their replacements."